# SR Flip Flop Latches

Tags: flipflop, latch, nand

Which gate, **NAND** or **NOR** is a better choice for making **SR Flip Flop** latch? Please, provide the reason too.

Comment: I think it depends on your choice. Whether you want to implement the whole design on NAND logic or NOR logic.

Comment: This looks like a school question without an attempt to solve.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which one fits the application better.

NAND:

- inputs are active-low
- for the Q output, "set" has priority over "reset"

NOR:

- inputs are active-high
- for the Q output, "reset" has priority over "set"

**Extra Credit**

Some applications require a two-phase clock. What is the subtle, but important difference between the following two circuits?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmfMXV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The question is about latches. How does one input have priority over the other?

Comment: @ShashankVM: In a NAND latch, if the "set" input is asserted (low), the Q output will be high regardless of the state of the "reset" input. However, in the NOR latch, asserting the "set" input (high) will be overridden if the "reset" input is also asserted, driving the Q output low. Sometimes this subtle difference is important in an application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Mr. Dave Tweed. I am able to understand now. I did not know that Set has priority over Reset in a NAND latch and vice versa for a NOR latch. Other readers can read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/323863/238188

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are identical except that one is active high and the other is active low.