# What is the function of a forward inverter and an inverted inverter in parallel in a digital circuit?

Tags: inverter, flipflop, differential, divider

When I was simulating a divider using two D-latch as shown below (two D-latches in series,) I found that the circuit in the red rectangular is key to the differential D-latch.

In fact, the circuit in the red rectangular is made up of a forward inverter and an inverted inverter in parallel. If not connecting that circuit, the differential D-latch performs poorly. If connected that circuit, it performs well. If I only use one forward inverter, it still performs poorly.

What is the function of a forward inverter and an inverted inverter in parallel in a digital circuit? What's the principle?

[image]

Comment: I have never heard these terms: "Forward inverter" and "Inverted inverter".

Comment: I don't know how to describe it. For a simple inverter consists of a NMOS and a PMOS, forward means from the gate to drain and inverted means from drain to gate as shown below.

Comment: The red rectangle IS the "memory". The other part is only "combinatorial" used as set/reset function.

Comment: That's right. It functions as a memory element. (Or Stabilize the output)

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/591677/how-does-an-sr-latch-actually-work/591707#591707

Answer (score 0):

These are "cross-coupled inverters" and they form a simple latch storage element. You will see that this is also the heart of a typical static RAM bit. In practice, the sizes of all of the transistors in your latch circuit must be selected carefully for proper electrical behavior.