# SR flip-flop with Preset and Clear should not work as described

Tags: logic-gates, flipflop, nand, sequential-logic

In the presented flip-flop, suppose the Enable signal is high, the S is low, and R is high. Now we set the Preset low (0) and the Clear high (1). In this condition, we expect Q=1 and Q'=0.

But checking the circuit gives us contradictory outputs. Because the Preset is low, the output of the upper NAND gate would be 1 and therefore Q=1. Since the R is high, the R* would be low (0) and therefore the output of the downside NAND gate would be also 1 or we can say Q^=1. That means both Q and Q' need to be high which is not possible.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "should not work" this way? It works how it works; if it doesn't work the way you want it to work then change the design.

Comment: Q and Q' being high at the same time is possible.  It's just not allowed if you want to use it as a flip-flop.

Answer (score 1):

By holding both the /Preset input Low and R input High you are forcing the flip-flop into an unstable (illegal) state.

When you change either of those inputs, the flip-flop will change to a legal state.

Answer (score 0):

> It means both Q and Q-complement need to be high which is not possible.

This is not a good point of view and analysis.
For analyzing this circuit, one should say first ... that the 2 outputs are labelled   Q1 and Q2 ... and that ****if some conditions are met**, Q1 & Q2 could be complementary states**.

One must do a "complete" analysis before saying there is a "problem".
Note that for such analysis, it is very important to check all the delays associated with each gate, because behavior can be "different" ...

Check my post at [this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/577071/for-an-rs-flip-flop-what-if-s-1-r-0-q-0-and-q%CC%85-1-is-it-legal-or-not) for the R-S FF with NAND gates.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the circuit is ok, preset Signal Signal take over the clock and S input cause Q is 1, Q' is 0, and CLEAR SIGNAL take over or bypasses the clock and reset Signal, cause Q goes to 0 and the Q' goes to zero.